# error in summary raise NotImplementedError

Tags: python

Here is my code for Ridge regression, when trying to output a summary, it gives an error

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats # для расчетов
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels . api as sm # для построения модели
data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/katya/Desktop/regressii/dan11.csv", sep =';')
y = data.values[:, 0] 
X = data.values[:, 1:]
print(X)
model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit_regularized(method='elastic_net', alpha=1.0, L1_wt=0.0)
print(results.summary())
```

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\katya\Desktop\regressii\strach.py", line 12, in 
print(results.summary())
File "C:\Users\katya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 1177, in summary
raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError

Help with advice, please

Comment: What version of statsmodels are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: I have never used this library.

At first glance, it really does look to be just not implemented (and therefore presumably a bug in the library).

Docs for OLS.fit_regularized: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit_regularized.html

This says that RegularizedResults are returned.

Source code seems to be here: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/base/elastic_net.html

You can see:

```py
class RegularizedResults(Results):
    """
    Results for models estimated using regularization

    Parameters
    ----------
    model : Model
        The model instance used to estimate the parameters.
    params : ndarray
        The estimated (regularized) parameters.
    """
    def __init__(self, model, params):
        super(RegularizedResults, self).__init__(model, params)

    @cache_readonly
    def fittedvalues(self):
        """
        The predicted values from the model at the estimated parameters.
        """
        return self.model.predict(self.params)
```

For Results base class, the code is here: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/base/model.html
and looks like

```
class Results(object):
    """
    Class to contain model results

    Parameters
    ----------
    model : class instance
        the previously specified model instance
    params : ndarray
        parameter estimates from the fit model
    """
    def __init__(self, model, params, **kwd):
        self.__dict__.update(kwd)
        self.initialize(model, params, **kwd)
        self._data_attr = []
        # Variables to clear from cache
        self._data_in_cache = ['fittedvalues', 'resid', 'wresid']

    def initialize(self, model, params, **kwargs):
        """
        Initialize (possibly re-initialize) a Results instance.

        Parameters
        ----------
        model : Model
            The model instance.
        params : ndarray
            The model parameters.
        **kwargs
            Any additional keyword arguments required to initialize the model.
        """
        self.params = params
        self.model = model
        if hasattr(model, 'k_constant'):
            self.k_constant = model.k_constant


    def _transform_predict_exog(self, exog, transform=True):

        is_pandas = _is_using_pandas(exog, None)
        exog_index = None
        if is_pandas:
            if exog.ndim == 2 or self.params.size == 1:
                exog_index = exog.index
            else:
                exog_index = [exog.index.name]

        if transform and hasattr(self.model, 'formula') and (exog is not None):
            # allow both location of design_info, see #7043
            design_info = (getattr(self.model, "design_info", None) or
                           self.model.data.design_info)
            from patsy import dmatrix
            if isinstance(exog, pd.Series):
                # we are guessing whether it should be column or row
                if (hasattr(exog, 'name') and isinstance(exog.name, str) and
                        exog.name in design_info.describe()):
                    # assume we need one column
                    exog = pd.DataFrame(exog)
                else:
                    # assume we need a row
                    exog = pd.DataFrame(exog).T
            orig_exog_len = len(exog)
            is_dict = isinstance(exog, dict)
            try:
                exog = dmatrix(design_info, exog, return_type="dataframe")
            except Exception as exc:
                msg = ('predict requires that you use a DataFrame when '
                       'predicting from a model\nthat was created using the '
                       'formula api.'
                       '\n\nThe original error message returned by patsy is:\n'
                       '{0}'.format(str(str(exc))))
                raise exc.__class__(msg)
            if orig_exog_len > len(exog) and not is_dict:
                if exog_index is None:
                    warnings.warn('nan values have been dropped', ValueWarning)
                else:
                    exog = exog.reindex(exog_index)
            exog_index = exog.index

        if exog is not None:
            exog = np.asarray(exog)
            if exog.ndim == 1 and (self.model.exog.ndim == 1 or
                                   self.model.exog.shape[1] == 1):
                exog = exog[:, None]
            exog = np.atleast_2d(exog)  # needed in count model shape[1]

        return exog, exog_index

    def predict(self, exog=None, transform=True, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Call self.model.predict with self.params as the first argument.

        Parameters
        ----------
        exog : array_like, optional
            The values for which you want to predict. see Notes below.
        transform : bool, optional
            If the model was fit via a formula, do you want to pass
            exog through the formula. Default is True. E.g., if you fit
            a model y ~ log(x1) + log(x2), and transform is True, then
            you can pass a data structure that contains x1 and x2 in
            their original form. Otherwise, you'd need to log the data
            first.
        *args
            Additional arguments to pass to the model, see the
            predict method of the model for the details.
        **kwargs
            Additional keywords arguments to pass to the model, see the
            predict method of the model for the details.

        Returns
        -------
        array_like
            See self.model.predict.

        Notes
        -----
        The types of exog that are supported depends on whether a formula
        was used in the specification of the model.

        If a formula was used, then exog is processed in the same way as
        the original data. This transformation needs to have key access to the
        same variable names, and can be a pandas DataFrame or a dict like
        object that contains numpy arrays.

        If no formula was used, then the provided exog needs to have the
        same number of columns as the original exog in the model. No
        transformation of the data is performed except converting it to
        a numpy array.

        Row indices as in pandas data frames are supported, and added to the
        returned prediction.
        """
        exog, exog_index = self._transform_predict_exog(exog,
                                                        transform=transform)

        predict_results = self.model.predict(self.params, exog, *args,
                                             **kwargs)

        if exog_index is not None and not hasattr(predict_results,
                                                  'predicted_values'):
            if predict_results.ndim == 1:
                return pd.Series(predict_results, index=exog_index)
            else:
                return pd.DataFrame(predict_results, index=exog_index)
        else:
            return predict_results


    def summary(self):
        """
        Summary

        Not implemented
        """
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Best of luck solving your issue.  Perhaps someone with more knowledge of the library can help.